# jQuery delay() not working as intended

Tags: javascript

Working on a small piece of code for a custom shopping cart.  I want to change a button to show a success message for 2 seconds, then revert the button back to the original HTML.

HTML...

```
<button id="42" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="button" onclick="added_to_order('42')">1st Semester<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right float-right"></span></button>
```

Javascript...

```
function added_to_order(id){
    var old_html = $('#' + id + '').html();

    $('#' + id + '').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Added to your order!');
    $('#' + id + '').removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-success').delay(2000).html(old_html);
}
```

Everything is fine, except I'm not getting the delay of 2 seconds before the button is updated with the old HTML.

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to use the `setTimeout` function in this case.

```
function added_to_order(id){
    var old_html = $('#' + id + '').html();

    $('#' + id + '').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Added to your order!');

    $('#' + id + '').removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-success');

    setTimeout(function() {

        $('#' + id + '').html(old_html);

    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: did u try this out?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that any old function qualifies to be a valid member of the jQuery effects queue.  I've wrapped your code in some [queue](https://api.jquery.com/queue/) function calls.  Take a look at the other examples on that page for more ideas.

```js
function added_to_order(el){
    var old_html = $(el).html();

    $(el).html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Added to your order!');
    $(el)
      .queue(function () {
        $(el).removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-success').dequeue();
      })
      .delay(2000)
      .queue(function () {
        $(el).html(old_html).dequeue();
      });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="button" onclick="added_to_order(this)">1st Semester<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right float-right"></span></button>
```

Comment: works fine :) but u could have given a simpler one ;)